# Choosing the right AWS RDS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm setting with RDS instance for our service.

We have about 50 tables. Out of 50, we have a particular table which we will be reading and writing mostly. That table is currently at 100GB.

We are looking at AWS RDS for MySQL and our current budget allows us to choose either db.r3.xlarge or db.m4.xlarge.

db.m4.xlarge    = 4 CPU and 16 GB RAM with High Network Performance.
db.r3.xlarge    = 4 CPU and 30.5 RAM with Moderate Network Performance.

So, which one should I choose? I'm guessing r3.xlarge since it provides more RAM. However, will the network performance have a great impact on the service?

Comment: Why not try both & benchmark ? Will only cost you a few $

Comment: Partially opinion based, but probably still a valid question.  Given budget constraints, memory is usually the resource you want to prioritize in favor of almost anything else, with InnoDB, which is the storage engine you need to use with RDS, and the "moderate" network performance is likely not to be a negative factor.

Comment: I would like to recommend taking a look at RDS Aurora - while you perform benchmark. And please share the results or at least the decision if Aurora helped you. Migrating from RDS MySQL to Aurora is straight forward.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that it's simply a matter of rebooting the RDS instance to change the instance type.  So if you end up with an over or under powered server you can simply shut it down, change it to use a different instance type, then restart it. You won't lose any data, configuration settings, etc. and you're now running on a different instance type.

Comment: @NaveenVijay, RDS Aurora doesn't work on my region - Singapore. So I think I'll stay away from it for now.

Comment: even if your budget allows, I would start with a db.m4.large (lower instance) and see if you need to upgrade

Comment: @FrédéricHenri, hello, the price for both is similar. However, r3.xlarge has 31GB RAM. Btw, for a table 100GB large, is 31GB RAM enough to perform well?

Comment: the price for x-large is similar but I think even large instance (m4) can suit you, I'll encourage to start small and size up if needed. I have tables with 200+ GB (mainly blob documentation) and other tables with 10+ million records (with lot of columns) and m4.large suits me well, but then it depends you IOPS and the workload on the instance, not only the RAM of the machine

Comment: @FrédéricHenri, I see. I have r3.xlarge with 5000 PIOPS and 600GB storage. However, my PIOPS is bottlenecked at 1800 PIOPS. Any idea why?

Comment: I dont know, maybe open a new question with your full setup and the current monitoring - it might be limited by the bandwidth of the EC2 instance eg

Comment: @FrédéricHenri, I've posted here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744104/aws-rds-piops-bottlenecked

Comment: https://www.apptio.com/emerge/choosing-the-right-rds-instance-for-the-job/

Answer (score 2):

There is no right answer to this.

If budget is a bigger concern than performance, go with the smaller instance initially.

If performance is more of an issue than budget, go with the bigger one initially.

In either case, you test the performance of whatever you picked at first and adjust the size up/down based on your own budget/performance curve that nobody else could know but you.

Comment: Thank for the answer. For MySQL instance with big tables, do you consider CPU or RAM first? I think AWS Moderate Network Performance is at 100MB/s which should not be a problem.