# AWS RDS PIOPS bottlenecked

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm running the following rds instance. However, my write PIOPS is bottlenecked at 20% of the allocated PIOPS.

```
db.r3.xlarge
Provisioned IOPS (SSD)
5000 PIOPS
600 GB
```

[image]

Do you have any ideas why it's stuck there?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your RDS instance type I/O are limited by two factors. IOPS and throughput. As you don't reach your IOPS limit it's probably your throughput which stuck here.

You have a very interesting piece of documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html#USER_PIOPS.Realized).

You could try to upgrade from r3.xlarge to r3.2xlarge to test your throughput needs and update accordingly.